# installing socket.io outputs (node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log) || (exit 0) and path to rebuild

Tags: node.js, socket.io, npm

I know that there are some questions about that, i read it but i didn't find a solution to solve it and the output that i get it's different from other users becuase i don't get any message about Microsoft or  other things.

The messages that i get are:

```
> ws@0.5.0 install E:\wamp\www\sandbox\chat\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\engine.io\node_modules\ws
> (node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log) || (exit 0)


E:\wamp\www\sandbox\chat\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\engine.io\node_modules\ws>node        
"C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild
/

> ws@0.4.31 install E:\wamp\www\sandbox\chat\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules
\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-client\node_modules\ws
> (node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log) || (exit 0)


E:\wamp\www\sandbox\chat\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-client\node_modules\ws>node 
"C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild

socket.io@1.2.1 node_modules\socket.io
├── debug@0.7.4
├── has-binary-data@0.1.3 (isarray@0.0.1)
├── socket.io-adapter@0.3.1 (object-keys@1.0.1, debug@1.0.2)
├── socket.io-parser@2.2.2 (isarray@0.0.1, component-emitter@1.1.2, benchmark@1.
0.0, json3@3.2.6)
├── engine.io@1.4.3 (base64id@0.1.0, debug@1.0.3, engine.io-parser@1.1.0, ws@0.5
.0)
└── socket.io-client@1.2.1 (indexof@0.0.1, to-array@0.1.3, component-bind@1.0.0,
 object-component@0.0.3, component-emitter@1.1.2, has-binary@0.1.5, parseuri@0.0
.2, engine.io-client@1.4.3)
```

I would like to know how i can fix it, but i would like to know what is `ws` too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That looks like `ws` was installed successfully.  Are you having any problems running your app/server?  If so, please upload the `npm-debug.log` as a gist https://github.com/gist and post the link here.

As far as "What is `ws`", you can read about it here: https://github.com/einaros/ws#ws-a-nodejs-websocket-library

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried to write some lines and the module worked fine, it not shows any error, maybe that outputs are something normal because it happened installing the `mongodb` package too.